# I am getting error while importing dump file in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am getting following error message.

```
    Error importing dump file -
    Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Apr 6 08:01:06 2023
    Version 19.3.0.0.0
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
    Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
    ORA-39002: invalid operation
    ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
   ORA-29283: invalid file operation: cannot open file [29435]
```

Comment: i did not find any solution from the related questions.

Comment: is this issue related to version or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error:

> ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.

In order to import data using Data Pump Import utility (it is unclear whether you use it, or is it the *original* IMP utility; which one?), you have to have a **directory** (Oracle object which points to operating system directory (folder)) and certain **privileges** on that directory granted to user which is using it. Directory is usually located on the database server (not your local PC, unless PC actually *is* the database server).

Let's **presume** user you're using in this operation is named `DIPAK`, while directory name is `EXPIMP_DIR`. Privileged user (such as `SYS`) has to

```
grant read, write on directory expimp_dir to dipak;
```

As you (actually, the Import utility) can't **open the log file**, it looks as if you have only `READ` privilege, and not WRITE. If that's so, then additionally grant `WRITE` privilege as well.

Comment: Permission is already given like rw-r-r---- for that schmea

Comment: it is working fine for one of the db server but i have tried to another server it is not working and shows the above error.

Comment: "Permission" you're talking about (rw-r-r----; *nix, right?) is related to **operating system level privileges**. I'm talking about **database privileges**. Two different things.

Comment: Actually there was an space issue in the linux server where the file was dumped.

Comment: Aha! It would be nice if Oracle reported something like that ("low space on disk"). Thank you for letting us know!